# How to say “The crowd” as in a "Crowd in a concert"

Tags: vocabulary

I'm interested to see if there is a specific translation for "Crowd" as in "crowd at a concert". To say "We entered the crowd at the concert" would it be 那一群人？ or 观众？ or is there a better way to express this？

Comment: **听众** probably fits concert better: hence all the listening they do! **观众** is more for *watching*.

Comment: Just depends on the situation: 1) The crowd at a concert （音乐会的听众） 2) The crowd watching the football game（看球的观众）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. For "crowd" in "the crowd in a concert" we say "聽眾"; for "crowd' in "the crowd in a ball game" we say "觀眾".

Answer (score 1):

"听众" and "观众" are two kinds of "audiences". The word "crowd" itself means "人群" or "众人".

"The crowd at a concert" = (听) 音乐会的人群 = 音乐会的听众

"The crowd watching the game" = 看比赛的人群 = 比赛的观众

Therefore if you want the translation of the word "crowd" I will suggest "人群" or "众人" rather than "听众" or "观众".